# how to update form data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter.

I am using codeigniter for this project. I have not getting how to update form data in the database. I have inserting,showing data in the databse is done. But I cant understand, how to update data in the database.

My controller:

```
    class User extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct() {
            // Call the Model constructor
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('usermodel');
        }

        public function insert() {
            $this->load->view('userview');

            if ($this->input->post('submit')) {

                $this->usermodel->save();
            }
        }

        public function display() {
            $data = array();
            $data['result'] = $this->usermodel->get_contents();
            $this->load->view('usergrid', $data);
        }

        public function edit() {
            $data = array();
            $get = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc();
            $data['result'] = $this->usermodel->entry_update( $get['id'] );

            $this->load->view('useredit', $data);
             if ($this->input->post('submit')) {

                $this->usermodel->entry_update1($get['id']);
            }
        }


    }
```

model:

```
        <?php

        class Usermodel extends CI_Model {

            public function __construct() {
                // Call the Model constructor
                parent::__construct();
            }

            public function save() {

                //print_r($this->input->post('name'));

                $data = array(
                    'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                    'age' => $this->input->post('age'),
                    'address' => $this->input->post('address')
                );
                //var_dump($this->db);

                $this->db->insert('user', $data);
            }

            public function get_contents() {
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('user');
                $query = $this->db->get();
                return $result = $query->result();
            }


            public function entry_update( $id ) {

                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('user');
                $this->db->where('id',$id );
                $query = $this->db->get();
                return $result = $query->row_array();

            }
            public function entry_update1($id) {
              $data = array(
       
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'age' => $this->input->post('age'),
        'address' => $this->input->post('address')
                );

                 $this->db->where('id', $id);
                $this->db->update('user', $data);

            }

        }
        ?>
```

view:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>user registration</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form  action="edit"  method="POST" name="myform">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>">
                username :<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $result['name'] ?>"></br>
                age      :<input type="text" name="age" value="<?php echo $result['age'] ?>"></br>
                Address  :<input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $result['address'] ?>"></br>

                <input type="submit" value="update" name="submit">
            </form>
        </body>

    </html>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only passing $id in

`$this->usermodel->entry_update1($get['id']);`

and in function u did

```
public function entry_update1($id) {
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('user', $data);
}
```

so you have to pass $data also in you function call

`$this->usermodel->entry_update1($get['id'], $data);`

```
public function entry_update1($id, $data) {
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('user', $data);
}
```

Comment: thanx Rana but showing error... Array to string conversion

Comment: you $data array should be $data = array('title' => $this->input->post('title'),'name' => $this->input->post('name'),'date' => $this->input->post('date')); //replace your db fields

Answer (score 1):

Just by having a quick look, I can see you're not passing anything to the $data in your entry_update1 function;

```
public function entry_update1($id) {

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('user', $data);

}
```

You're trying to update 'user' with $data, but you haven't set $data.

Comment: You're only passing an ID to this function ($id), but this function is looking for another variable, called $data used within the update()

Answer (score 0):

You have to run update query this way in CodeIgniter.

```
        public function entry_update1($id,$data) {

            $this->db->set($data);
            $this->db->where('id',$id);
            $update = $this->db->update('user');
            if($update)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
               return false;
            }

         }
```