# how to edit the column names of db from browser itself in codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, dynamic

I want to pass the database field names in url and edit them in codeigniter. please explain with small code

**view page code**

```
  <?php
    foreach($field as $r=>$field) {
     ?>

     <?php   echo "<a href = '".base_url()."index.php/product/edit/"
                      .$field->name."'>Edit</a>";  ?>
     <?php echo "<a href = '".base_url()."index.php/product/deleteid/"
                      .$field->name."'>Delete</a>";    ?> <?php  
                }
    ?>
```

**controller code**

I dont wheather this right or not . so please explain with small example

```
function criterionlist()
{
                $this->load->database();
                $this->load->helper(array('url', 'form'));
                $this->load->model('p_model');
                $data['field'] = $this->p_model->get_field();
                $this->load->view('criterionlist',$data);


}
```

Comment: can you explain your exact issue? where are you stuck in process?

Comment: @prakashtank i want to edit the field names of database from browser. i need to code according to the above condition..      _for example  name, email_ are my field names mean i want to change them from browser

Comment: so make an array and pass that array to the controller and then execute the update function.

Comment: i dont know what to do so please made a small example with 2 field names

Comment: please check this link for better idea :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27356776/how-to-update-form-data-in-codeigniter

Comment: that link is not related to my question . can you get my question

Comment: you want to pass the field names in url. but that is not the right way . but still you can achieve this with `$this->uri->segment()` function

Comment: Do you want to alter a tables actual field names? i.e modify a table?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw yes , i want to edit them from webpage

Comment: Have you read the codeigniter userguide... https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html#modifying-a-column-in-a-table

Comment: yes. but i dont know how to implete this. pllease explain with small example if you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 foreach($field as $r=>$field) {


 <a href ="<?php echo base_url("index.php/product/edit/".$field->name)?>">Edit</a>
 <a href ="<?php echo base_url("index.php/product/deleteid/".$field->name)?>">Delete</a>  
}
```

In your product controller your method EDIT

```
public function EDIT($name)
{
    $post = $this->input->post();
  //your parameters to edit
    $data = array(
        '' => $post[''],
        '' => $post[''],
        '' => $post[''],
    );
    $this->load->database();
     $this->load->helper(array('url', 'form'));
     $this->load->model('p_model');
     $updated = $this->p_model->editproduct($data, $name);
    if($updated)
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', "product updated successfully");
        redirect(); //redirect according to your requirement 
    }
    else
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('unsuccesss', "There is some issue please try later");
        redirect(); //redirect according to your requirement 
    }
}
```

In your model

```
public function editproduct($data, $name) //you can use ID instead of name
{
   $this->db->where('product name', $name);
   return $this->db->update('table-name', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you means by field name is a table column names, then you could use `list_fields()` on your `$data` :

```
$data['field'] = $this->p_model->list_fields();
```

Comment: yes table column names i want to edit  table column names from browser. i need to code for this method . please explain with small examle