# How can I update data with arrays in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am having a trouble in updating my data with an occurring  error of `Array of String`
I am using MVC, CodeIgniter.

What I have done is import excel file and update the data in my system. I would like to update my data which you can see on the model. First, I am trying to use static data for me to check if it does work, see the model. Please do not make this as duplicate as every problem has different ways of solution. Thank you for having your time.

Model:

```
   public function updateGrades($updateFields){  
        $this->db->where('studentID', 200171419);
        $this->db->where('updtStatus', 1);
        return $this->db->update('tbl_tt_academicinfo', $updateFields);
    }
```

Comment: you will get an answer from this link[ update form data in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27356776/how-to-update-form-data-in-codeigniter) i hope so... Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as long as the `$updateFields` is a multidimensional array and codeigniter update function handles the arrays of one dimension `['key'=>'value']`, you have to use the update query in for loop like this

```
 public function updateGrades($updateFields){  
        foreach($updateFields as $recoredData){
            $this->db->where('studentID', 200171419); // prefer to make it dynamic $recoredData['studentID']
            $this->db->where('updtStatus', 1);
            $this->db->update('tbl_tt_academicinfo', $recoredData);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function updateGrades($updateFields){  
   $this->db->where('updtStatus', 1);        
   return $this->db->update_batch('tbl_tt_academicinfo', $updateFields, 'studentID');
}
```